# Writing updated XML to originally parsed file

Tags: groovy, gradle, xmlslurper

I have a `gradle.build` where I am trying to:

1. read an XML file
2. use `XmlSlurper` to update an attribute in the read XML file
3. write the updated XML back to the originally parsed xml file.

The third step only works if I write the modified XML to a *new non-existing* XML file, but *not* the *originally parsed XML file*.

What is the simplest way to write the modified XML to the originally parsed XML file?

---

My code so far:

```
def inFile = file('file.xml')
def outFile = file('_file.xml')

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(inFile)

// update xml code here

def outBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def outWriter = outFile.newWriter()
XmlUtil.serialize(outBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield xml }, outWriter)
```

I would like `outFile` to be `file.xml` so that it overwrites the original XML file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens if you do:

```
def inFile = file( 'file.xml' )
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse( inFile )

xml.appendNode {
    haha( 'tim_yates' )
}

inFile.withWriter { outWriter ->
    XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield xml }, outWriter )
}
```

Is it just not written? (seems to work for me)

Comment: Hi @tim_yates, thanks for the quick reply. Your sample code works perfectly and it is a valid answer. My code is still not working however but it must be for another reason altogether (not exactly what that reason is yet but I am basically first exploding a zip and then, I am trying to update an xml file in the exploded archive. In my code I try to get to the xml file via a FileTree as I don't know the exact path to the file ahead of time). Anyway, I'll close this post for now as your answer pretty much answers my initial question! Thanks again, PM.

Comment: @tim_yates what does the `.bind{ mkp.yield xml }` part do?

Comment: @ArtB I think it's a shortcut to http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilderHelper.html